# How do you calculate the implied liquidity of an option?

Tags: options, liquidity

How does one calculate the implied liquidity of a specific option contract given a set of vanilla puts and calls with various strikes and maturities on a single underlying?

Answer (score 7):

From *[Implied Liquidity : Towards stochastic liquidity modeling and liquidity trading](https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0009713/ImpliedLiquidity.pdf)*

> We will call the parameter, ﬁtting
>   the bid-ask spread (under a symmetric
>   distortion) around the mid price, the
>   implied liquidity parameter. Hence for
>   the European Call option (strike K and
>   maturity T ) with given market bid (b)
>   and ask (a) prices, the implied
>   liquidity parameter is the speciﬁc λ >
>   0, such that:
>
> a = − exp(−rT )Eλ [−(ST − K )+ ] and b
>   = exp(−rT )Eλ [(ST − K )+ ]